# PyQt5 UI is inconsistent across different platforms

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a desktop application using pyqt5 because I need it to be cross platform but the UI is very inconsistent from a platform to another (the position of the widgets on the screen is different and sometimes they're on top of other widgets).

I'm new to pyqt5 and python in general so can you tell me why this is happening and how to fix it if possible?

PS: i'm using Qt designer to generate the UI and you can find all the code [here](https://github.com/cabiste69/GUI-launcher-for-portal-2-32PlayerMod)

here are some examples:

*on windows 10*

[image: GUI on windows 10]

*on linux mint* (ignore the missing images)

[image: GUI on linux mint]

Comment: Use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), also [in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: you may want to bundle a font with your application rather than using system fonts to ensure spacing consistency. Keep track of DPI scaling, as various operating systems handle this differently. Don't leave things default; use stylesheets. etc...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.